# Making a modal responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m working on a frontend excercise I set up for improving myself and I have hit a real huge headache.

I am trying to make my modal responsive to mobile and tablets. As part of a wordpress plugin that i am creating as an exercise [see link here](https://github.com/globalfoodbook/mailchimp-foodcook-subscribe).

This is being use temporarily on a [food recipe website](http://globalfoodbook.com)

But so far, I think I am close.

I have the [jsfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/kengimel/kzy2a6p7).

But my main problem is with the CSS. I have left the comments on some things and options I tried.

```css
#overlay:backdrop {
  /*
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  */
}
#overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  /*
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 30%;
  top: 30%;
  /*
  -webkit-transform: translate(-27%, -10%);
  transform: translate(-27%, -10%);
  */
  text-align: center;
}
#overlay div#gfb_newsletter_signup_form {
  max-width: 750px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-height: 750px;
  min-height: 250px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
a.boxclose {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #605F61;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  /*
  padding: 11px 7px 17px 7px;
  */
  padding: 11px 8px 15px;
}
.boxclose:before {
  content: "x";
}
.gfb_ebook_img {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  /*
  top: -20px;
  left: -30px;
  */
}
#gfb_newsletter_signup_form h1 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /*style="margin-bottom:20px; font-size:18px;"*/
}
div#p-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: if you use bootstrap your modal will be automatically responsive @ ikenna

Comment: I agree with @siva - it's far easier to build off a framework than from scratch. A framework like bootstrap will make your life easier, and you can always theme/customize it however you want.

Comment: Could you tell, what are you wanting to get and what the problem is? I'm to lazy to read this amount of code...

Comment: yes i agree with your comment @  troglodite but we can use the framework only when we know the basic and usage of the particular classes

Comment: @siva I am challenging myself with this exercise.. so a framework is not what i need..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change your overlay to absolutely positioned (that way you can have coordinates for the inner div). Then set top, left, right, bottom all equal to 0, and margin auto. This will center the box on any screen, assuming your dimensions are percentages. Then do the same for #gfb_newsletter_signup_form but add some height to it, perhaps a percentage that makes sense within your min and max values.

So your #overlay and #gfb_newsletter_signup_form might look something like this:

```
#overlay {
  visibility: hidden;

  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}


#overlay div#gfb_newsletter_signup_form {
  max-width: 750px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-height: 750px;
  min-height: 250px;

  height: 30%;

  margin: 5px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kzy2a6p7/16/

Comment: Hey thanks for providing with this.. It has helped me with creating an open source wordpress widget. see this [link](http://https://github.com/globalfoodbook/mailchimp-foodcook-subscribe/blob/master/includes/assets/css/gfb_subscribe.css)

Answer (score 4):

You won't get very far with a responsive design that uses fixed pixel widths for modals.

For example, your overlay has:

```
#overlay div#gfb_newsletter_signup_form {
    max-width: 750px;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

On a tablet or phone, which may have less than 750px screen width, it will go off the viewport.

You should use percentages instead - in your fiddle I changed the above line to

```
 max-width:40%;
```

and it fit in the jsfiddle window.

Even better, would be for you to study [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and make a proper responsive design

Comment: The big point here is look into those media queries. Sometimes % acts funky so you will need to research that, but that is the right route to go as well.

Answer (score 1):

use @media screen css query to define your model at different screen width.outside this query use class with width in % or em . but all class and ids with width in px should be define inside @media query

```
 @media screen and (max-width: screenwithinPx) {
      //define your class and id here having with and height in px
    .class{} 
           #Ids{}
        }
```